# Removing a jquery generated field not working

Tags: jquery, html, append, parent

I have a HTML form as below:

```
<div class="form_row">Add Note<input type="checkbox" name="add_note" id="add_note"></div>
    <div class="form_row" id="addDiv" style="display:none;">
        <div class="form_row">
             <h4><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h4>
            <div id="p_scents">
                <p>
                    <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_1"/></label>
                </p>
            <div id="new_notes">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript is:

```
$('#add_note').click(function(){
    if($("input[type='checkbox'][name='add_note']:checked").length > 0)
    {
    $('#addDiv').show(500);
    }else{
    $('#addDiv').hide(200);
    }
})

  var i = 2;
$('#addScnt').click(function(){

    var html = ''; 
    html += '<p>';
    html += '<label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_"'+i+'/><a href="#" id="cancel_field">Cancel</a></label>';
    html += '</p>';

    $('#new_notes').append(html);

    i++;
    });
    $('#cancel_field').click(function(){
    alert('Test ')
    $(this).parents('p').remove(); 
});
```

Now, my problem is when I click `cancel`, it does no do anything, neither alerts nor removes the parent div. What's wrong with the code?

EDIT:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tka55/)

Comment: IDs must be unique, could it be your issue?

Comment: @A.Wolff tried with class `cancel_field`, same result !

Comment: ya because you need to use delegation. Please next time try to post better indentation for code ;)

Comment: Have you noticed that you have 2 functions inside `$('#addScnt')`? First function creates elements, second add event handler. Try to move the second function to the the end of first function.

Comment: @Epsil0neR same mistake than i did, in fact '#cancel_field' click handler is not wrapped inside the other. Just one of worst case of indentation here ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff but still it need to be moved into element creating function, or use delegated event handler and then move outside `#addScnt` click handler

Comment: @Epsil0neR sorry misread your comment, but ya you are correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to delegate because it is a dynamically generated element:

```
$('#new_notes').on("click", "#cancel_field", function() { ...
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tka55/1/

Also, note that the `id` should be unique otherwise while adding multiple elements, you will again get into trouble.

Comment: True, i was confused by bad indentation. But still IDs must be unique

Comment: @A.Wolff: yes, of course. thanks for reminding. adding to the answer right away.

Comment: Thanks abhitalks..Working pefectly.

Answer (score 1):

When you add elements to the DOM after it has been loaded, you must bind them differenlty, using `bind` or `on` jquery function. They are not included on the event binding you defined in the DOM ready.

So you should do :

```
 var html = ''; 
        html += '<p>';
        html += '<label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_"'+i+'/><a href="#" class="cancel_field">Cancel</a></label>';
        html += '</p>';

        $('#new_notes').append(html);

        i++;
        });
        $('.cancel_field').on('click',function(){
        alert('Test ')
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use onclick for that.If you use click the listener will not be attached to added elements.

See this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/A6Q5C/

```
$('#new_notes').on('click','#cancel_field',function(){});
```

When you use `on` the you are attaching it to the parent div to which you are dynamically appending.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Added `class="cancel_field"`

```
      var i = 2;
    $('#addScnt').click(function(){

        var html = ''; 
        html += '<p>';
        html += '<label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_"'+i+'/><a href="#" class="cancel_field">Cancel</a></label>';
        html += '</p>';

        $('#new_notes').append(html);

        i++;
        });
        $('.cancel_field').click(function(){
        alert('Test ')
        $(this).parents('p').remove(); 
    });
```